# Parallel AsyncTasks make Huawei phone crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a Fragment containing a ListView, whose items are composed of some text and an image. Each image is downloaded asyncronously from my server with the use of an AsyncTask. Since the order of completion of these tasks is irrelevant, I recently set them to work in parallel by using the `executeOnExecutor()` method with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as argument. Tasks are launched inside the `getView()` method of the `BaseAdapter` attached to the list.

I tested it on LG, Samsung and HTC phones and all of this works smoothly and super fast, but the strange thing is that on a Huawei phone this new feature makes the phone crash sometimes while executing the tasks. It doesn't look like a "normal" crash, since the app just exits without any error dialog (nothing like "Unfortunately, xxx has stopped").

This did not happen on my phone (it's basically a bug report from a friend living far away) so I can't just debug it on my computer and see what happens. I've already set an `ExceptionHandler` inside my app, so each time it crashes on any phone I get the exception log sent to my server, however in this case no exception log is sent. It looks like the app dies for some reason before being able to send the log message. I thought about a memory issue, but the phone in question has 2GB of RAM and the work is not extremely intensive (max 3 or 4 asynctask at the same time). It was all working fine when I just lunched the AsyncTasks serially with the `execute()` command.

I would post some code but I don't know which part would be useful, it is all relatively standard. I'm running out of bullets here, what could I do in this case? Are you aware of any bugs of this kind specific to Huawei?

EDIT: The only potentially "dangerous" action that I perform inside the AsyncTasks is image decoding from a byte array, which could originate memory exceptions. However I handle it in the standard way to avoid memory issues inside the background task:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
imgBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray, 0, imgArray.length, options);

Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgBmp,150,150,true);
imgBmp.recycle();

return newBmp;
```

so I still don't understand why this happens, and why just on one phone.

Comment: please provide some stacktrace

Comment: I don't have any, since this happened on one of my tester's phone, and the ExceptionHandler is not sending the trace to the server for some reason. I know it's hard to figure out without a stacktrace, I was just wondering if anybody else had experienced a similar issue and could provide suggestions.

Comment: k - but without stacktrace or code chances of help are really low

Comment: @ligi I'm aware of that. This was just my last resort since I don't know what else to do. If I ever manage to get my hands on that phone I will be more precise.

Comment: Are you loading the image byte arrays in the `AsyncTask`? That could easily cause memory issues when executed in parallel.

Comment: @corsair992 yes, I'm downloading them from my server so I need to do that in background. They are very small images (like 50kb), and the phone has 2GB of RAM.

Comment: The memory limitation is caused by the total heap size, not the total available memory in the RAM. Note that you are also first decoding into a full-sized bitmap (which could be much larger than the actual size of the file) before scaling it to your desired dimensions.

Comment: @corsair992 of course it depends on the heap size, but I guessed that the heap size itself is correlated with the RAM, and that it would be the same on two phones with equal RAM (but I might be wrong). You're right I resize the bitmap, but I did this just to try every possibility, since anyway the bitmap was saved with the same 150x150 dimensions.